# React Native Filter by Category using Button or Touchableopacity

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

How to Filter the record based status on the button click in the react native ?

Here is the data I have:

```
[
   {
      "id":28,
      "Title":"Sweden",
      "Status":1
   },
   {
      "id":56,
      "Title":"USA",
      "Status":1
   },
   {
      "id":89,
      "Title":"England"
      "Status":1
   },
{
      "id":89,
      "Title":"England"
      "Status":2
   },
{
      "id":89,
      "Title":"England"
      "Status":2
   },
{
      "id":89,
      "Title":"England"
      "Status":3
   }
]
```

Here I have id, title, status..Now I need to filter this according to the status

Comment: Please add a minimal description of desired behavior, and your attempts code to reach it in order for us being more helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Critique

Although your question is very specific in terms of programming capabilities, it is very lacking in terms of context.
Keep in mind that people answering these questions do so in their own time, questions like yours, are sometimes really hard to cypher.

missing key elements in your question:

- At what stage should the filtering be done?
- Did you already try something that didn't work?
- Do you already have a running react-native app? or are you starting from scratch?
- Going with react-native, are you using hooks? or are extending the `React.Component` class?
- Is the issue you are having even react-native related? or just JavaScript? because with a quick google search, you would've landed here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

I could go on, but the bottom line, help us, help you,by painting a picture around your current situation, it will help you get faster, better answers.

I hop I won't discourage from participating in the future, but understand that these kind of question really make it hard to understand, what you need.

#### Answer

Now, to try to answer what I think you need answering.

like @nithinpp already stated, filtering arrays in JavaScript can be done with the `Array.prototype.filter()` method, it usage usually looks like so:

```js
// Example taken from the https://developer.mozilla.org/ website
const words = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];

const result = words.filter(word => word.length > 6);

console.log(result);
// expected output: Array ["exuberant", "destruction", "present"]
```

Within The React/React-Native realms, this method would have to be used, either inside a react(-native) component, or inside a utility-service/reducers/saga that filters said data, and passes it on to the component through props.

For the sake of this example, I'll be using react-hooks, and do the filtering inside a component, such a solution could look like so:

Playable Online Version using Expo Snack: https://snack.expo.dev/yTte5nPud

```js
//This is an example of online Emulator by https://aboutreact.com
import React, {useState, useMemo} from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button, FlatList } from 'react-native';


// Item Component To render single items
function Item(props) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Text>{props.item.id}: {props.item.Title} ({props.item.Status})</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

// Main App
const App = () => {
  // There are a lot of different ways to keep this info,
  // for the sake of this answer, I've put it in a useState hook
  const [fullList, setFullList] = useState([
    { "id":28, "Title":"Sweden", "Status":1 },
    { "id":56, "Title":"USA", "Status":1 },
    { "id":89, "Title":"England", "Status":1 },
    { "id":89, "Title":"England", "Status":2 },
    { "id":89, "Title":"England", "Status":2 },
    { "id":89, "Title":"England", "Status":3 } 
  ]);

  // Keep a statue of the current selected status
  const [status, setStatus] = useState('NONE')

  // the filtered list, cached with useMemo
  // the callback is call each time the status or the fullList changes
  const filteredList = useMemo(
    () => {
      if (status === 'NONE' ) return fullList
      return fullList.filter(item => status === item.Status)
    },
    [status, fullList]
  )

  // the onClick Method is a method that returns a method, which
  // updates the state based on the predefined status
  const onClick = (status) => () => {
      setStatus(status)
  }

  // render list using flat list, and the filter bar using standard buttons
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Selected Status: {status}</Text>
      <View style={styles.filterBar}>
        <Button title="Clear" onPress={onClick('NONE')} />
        <Button title="Status 1" onPress={onClick(1)} />
        <Button title="Status 2" onPress={onClick(2)} />
        <Button title="Status 3" onPress={onClick(3)} />
      </View>
      <FlatList
        style={styles.list}
        renderItem={Item}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        data={filteredList}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;

// some basic styling
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 8,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  list: {
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%'
  },
  filterBar: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      // flex: 0.2,
      height: 40,
  },
  item: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    padding: 8,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  }
});
```

#### Summary

Now This answer assumes a lot of things, I still don't know the extent of your knowledge regarding react-native, or if you even know how to use react-native components such as the FlatList, and this answer should not start explaining those as well, thus might end up confusing you and giving you an answer to something you haven't even asked, which I hope is not the case.

Anyways, I hope this helps, and maybe keep these points in mind in your next question

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter your data based on your condition.

For example,

```js
function filterArray(array, status){
  return array.filter(item => item.Status === status);
}
```

```js
const DATA =  [ { "id":28, "Title":"Sweden", "Status":1 }, { "id":56, "Title":"USA", "Status":1 }, { "id":89, "Title":"England", "Status":1 }, { "id":89, "Title":"England", "Status":2 }, { "id":89, "Title":"England", "Status":2 }, { "id":89, "Title":"England", "Status":3 } ];

function filterArray(array,status){
  return array.filter(item => item.Status === status);
}

const statusOneArray = filterArray(DATA, 1);
console.log(statusOneArray);
```